# Pass values for dropdown for EXT Js using JSON

Tags: extjs

I want to pass JSON list of values to dropdown wrote in ext js. i AM PAAING IT FROM java using the code

```
String json = "items:[{name:kiran,kumar,shetty}]"; 
return json;
```

But I am getting the error:
uncaught exception: Unable to parse the JSON returned by the server: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: [name:praveen,kiran,narendra]

Could anyone please let me know how to pass multiple values for dropdown?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid JSON. You should try something like

```
"{\"items\":[{\"name\":\"kiran\"},{\"name\":\"kumar\"},{\"name\":\"shetty\"}]}"
```